# Order by nested JSON field in Django admin

Tags: json, django, postgresql, django-models, django-admin

I've got model User with `meta` field, which stores JSON data:

```
{
    "info": {
        "f_name": "John".
        "l_name": "Doe",
        "nick": "foo",
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```

How can I specify ordering in Django admin by `meta['info']['l_name']`?

I've tried:

1. `ordering = ( 'meta__info__l_name' )`
2. `ordering = ( 'meta -> info ->> l_name' )`
3. `ordering ( RawSQL("main_user.meta -> 'info' ->> 'l_name'", [], ), )`

Also, `user.id DESC` sorting is applied by default, which also breaks the desired behaviour.

Django 2.1.2.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What version of Django are you using?

Comment: @solarissmoke Django 2.1.2